# Как десктопное приложение может послать запрос в интернет?

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Пример: 
У меня есть приложение на Java, которое хочет использовать Google Cloud Speech Recognition in real time. Каким образом можно это реализовать?

Comment: Есть множество способов и библиотек для http-запросов. В частности [стандартный http-клиент](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html). Но правильнее не изобретать велосипед, а взять библиотеку [google-cloud-speech](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-speech/0.67.0-beta).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо за ссылку! 
А можно для особоодаренных - как этим пользоваться или где об этом читать или какой запрос гуглить?

Comment: Всё есть как минимум в [официальной документации](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/).